# Problem Using the readability module from background.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to program a simple Firefox's extension using its API. In my background.js file, I have this piece of code:

```
const [currentTab] = await browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    
    await browser.tabs.executeScript(currentTab.id, {
      file: 'readability/Readability.js'
    });
    
   const reader = new Readability(htmlDocument);
```

Where readability/Readability.js points to Mozilla's readability module ([readability module](https://github.com/mozilla/readability)).

But when executing the constructor, I get this error:

```
Error in getReadableDocument(htmlDocument): ReferenceError: Readability is not defined
```

I tried many alternatives, with no success. For example:

-The most obvious alternative was to use an import in the background.js file, but this is not allowed.

-I also tried to look at the code of [readability-based-reader-view](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/readability-based-reader-view), which also uses that module, but it is quite complex and I couldn't replicate the functionality in a simple scenario.

-The webpage at [itsopensource](https://itsopensource.com/demos/readability/) is also very inspiring and its code is really very simple, but I don't know how to execute that code from within my background.js file.

I'm really stuck here, and it seems that it this should be a very simple problem to solve. Any tip is very welcome!